# My label shape is (3, 1, 1) and train shape (3, 3, 5) GOT ERROR

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, mnist

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

train_data = tf.constant([
    [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
     [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
    [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
     [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],
    [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
     [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]], ])
print(train_data)
train_labels = tf.constant([[[0]],
                            [[0]],
                            [[1]], ])
print(train_labels)
train_data = np.array(train_data)
train_labels = np.array(train_data)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

I am new to machine learning and could use some help. Trying to have in train data 3 situations and in train_label 3 labels to those situation.

It should be similar to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist/load_data

but when i try to run it i get this error:

> Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
> logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [9,1] and labels shape [45]
> [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_718]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have made a typo? Where you have

> train_data = np.array(train_data)
> train_labels = np.array(train_data)

the second line should be

> train_labels = np.array(train_labels)